# Excel - vlookup with priorization

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with the following data:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Unique line ID  | ID | Status         |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1               | AA | active         |
| 2               | AA | upgraded       |
| 3               | AA | out of service |
| 4               | AB | ...            |
-----------------------------------------
```

And I have another table where I have only the `ID`, and I need to match the `Status`, but I want to prioritize it and have the latest one, which is the biggest one ordered by `Unique line ID`.

So in this example for `AA`, I need to match the status `out of service`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Is Unique Line ID always in ascending order in your sheet?

Comment: Not necessarily, but the latest status has always the biggest Unique line ID

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH with Aggregate to get the max Unique Id:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$5/($B$2:$B$5=E2),1),$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this
It will find the last value (Your data should be sorted on ID[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your formulas short and easily understandable:

**Step 1:**

Add a column next to the `ID` column that combines the `Unique line ID` and the `ID` column. If the data is as per sheet below, on cell `C2`,  enter the formula `=A2&B2` and drag it down. This column can later be hidden.

[image: step1]

**Step 2:**

On the 2nd table, on the first status cell, enter the following [**array formula**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) and drag it down as needed.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(B:B=F2,A:A))&F2,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

**Note:** When you enter this in the first cell, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> since its an array formula. `{` and `}` will appear as in the screenshot after you do this.

[image: step2]